# SVN Server: 500 Error when connecting from client

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

I'm setting up a SVN server with Digest authentication. I get the following error when trying to connect with either the command line SVN client *or* with the Cornerstone client for Mac OS X, using HTTPS:

```
Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to OPTIONS request for 'https://user@server.domain.com/svn/repo'
     Status : 175002
```

(obviously, `user`, `server.example.com`, and `repo` are placeholders).

If I go to a web browser and go to `https://server.example.com/svn/repo` and enter the username and password, I am able to browse the repository without problems. I have double and triple checked for typos.

In my Apache logs, I get this error:

```
[Wed Apr 02 13:22:24 2014] [error] [client ::1] AuthUserFile not specified in the configuration
```

when I try to connect via a SVN client. The error does *NOT* appear when I authenticate on the website. I have only enabled digest authentication, and the authentication works fine from a web browser.

---

I switched the authentication module to mod_auth_digest_apple; it uses system accounts. It still complains about the AuthUserFile but the Apple module doesn't use it. Still interested in an answer if anyone has one.

Comment: What does the relevant part of your apache config look like?

Comment: @JennyD See http://serverfault.com/questions/586509/apache-svn-server-access-to-x-forbidden - there's a new error and I posted more detailed information there.

Comment: Don't ask multiple questions for the same issue. You are just making it harder for anyone wanting to help you to find the right place to do so.

Comment: The new question is about a different issue. Authentication works, and the client no longer gets a 500 error, but instead gets a permission denied from SVN. This issue was that the client couldn't authenticate at all.

Comment: I finally tracked down the issue to the server responding to OPTIONS requests with a 401 error. So I posted a question for that: http://serverfault.com/questions/586680/apache-returns-401-forbidden-for-options-requests