# Apache returns 401 forbidden for OPTIONS requests

Tags: apache-2.2

I've finally tracked down an error I've been having to Apache returning a 401 for ALL `OPTIONS` requests. This happens for any directory, including those that have no `Limit` or `Require` directives. These locations all respond to `GET` requests.

I've posted the httpd.conf at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d84e4e9721a49789f846 - I went through it but I can't find anything that looks like it's limiting `OPTIONS` requests.

As a further bit of information, the `OPTIONS` requests return 401 even if the user is authenticated (such as for the Subversion section at the bottom). That's the section I'm most interested in, but the requests fail server wide so it's not just that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: <Directory "/Library/Server/Web/Data/CGI-Executables">  AllowOverride None
   Options None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: @NickW Not sure what you mean... that doesn't do anything except on that directory, and that Options directive isn't the same as an OPTIONS request. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory

Comment: Yeah, you're right about that, what about some of the includes? `Include /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/other/*.conf` for example?

Comment: @NickW There's nothing in other, and I went through the rest of the includes. There's nothing in there that affects methods. The only thing I found that was even close was a rewrite rule that only affects methods other than OPTIONS and PROPFIND.

Comment: Any LimitExcept clauses?

Comment: @NickW Nope, no Limit clauses either.

Comment: I was wondering if it was other mac programs where they seem to have multiple config files, but not even that seems to be worth pursuing..

Comment: @NickW Nope, just standard Apache with the config files set up for Apple-specific features. Most of them are just aliases and a few rewrites that only go into effect when trying to access OSX specific services on a server where they're not activated.

Comment: Just noticed I forgot to write like in my previous sentence.. I can only think that there might be an .httaccess somewhere.

Comment: @NickW No .htaccess files, I already looked.

Comment: That's pretty crazy.. you didn't happen to compile apache did you?

Comment: Nope, it's the included version. 2.2.26 to be exact.

Comment: well, I'm stumped, hopefully someone else can offer more insight..

Comment: Yeah, I tried posting on IRC a few times but nobody's even bothered to try.